# How can I have <C-E> and <C-Y>'s normal mode functionalities also work in insert mode?

Tags: key-bindings, normal-mode, insert-mode, control-character, execute

Once I've asked [a general question about special characters](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/37228/special-characters-escaped-special-characters-escape-sequences-and-terminal-c), but I've not really pulled anything out of it.

So now I'm asking a very specific question.

I want to have <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>y</kbd> behave in insert mode as they do in normal mode.

(Yes, I have looked at [`:help i_CTRL-E` and `:help i_CTRL-Y`](https://vimhelp.org/insert.txt.html#i_CTRL-E), but I have no idea when such a functionality will ever be useful to me, so I'd happily drop it in favour of normal mode [`CTRL-E`](https://vimhelp.org/scroll.txt.html#CTRL-E) and [`CTRL-Y`](https://vimhelp.org/scroll.txt.html#CTRL-Y).)

Here's my main failed attempt:

```
inoremap <c-e> <esc>:<c-u>exe "normal \<c-e>"<cr>a
```

but clearly there are a few variations of it where I've tried to more `\`, or to insert <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> by hitting it after <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>.

And even if the above command worked, I think it would have the problem of screwing up the undo sequence because it exits insert mode and then re-enters it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

As @D.BenKnoble pointed out this is the simplest way:

```
inoremap <C-E> <C-O><C-E>
```

**Original answer**

Try using `<cmd>...<cr>` instead:

```
inoremap <c-e> <cmd>exe "normal! \<c-e>"<cr>
```

`:h <cmd>` excerpt:

```
*<Cmd>* *:map-cmd*

The special text <Cmd> begins a "command mapping", it executes the command
directly without changing modes.  Where you might use ":...<CR>" in the
{rhs} of a mapping, you can instead use "<Cmd>...<CR>".
Example: 
    noremap x <Cmd>echo mode(1)<CR>

This is more flexible than `:<C-U>` in Visual and Operator-pending mode, or
`<C-O>:` in Insert mode, because the commands are executed directly in the
current mode, instead of always going to Normal mode.  Visual mode is
preserved, so tricks with |gv| are not needed.
```

PS,

Your mapping could be also written as

```
inoremap <c-e> <c-o>:exe "normal \<lt>c-e>"<cr>
```

Where you change `<` to a `<lt>` as otherwise `\<c-e>` is literally interpreted by a command line your are in when mapping is in effect. (and `<C-e>` is goto end of cmdline)

Comment: Would you believe that I knew about this and probably even used it once or twice? Ufff, things just slip out of my mind so easily! Thanks for the perfect solution! :D

Comment: But out of curiosity, can my original attempt be fixed by writing appropriately the stuff inside `"..."`? Or is it just not possible to do it that way?

Comment: to be fair, it looks like a vim bug to me, @Enlico

Comment: What bug? I mean, do you refer to a software bug, or to a design bug (as in, Vim is behaving as it was designed to, even if nobody likes this behavior)? I'm asking because I would report it... I mean, for what is worth, considering your proposed solution is better anyway.

Comment: @Enlico https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/11165

Comment: Your mapping should also work, @Enlico, the fact it didn't seems like a vim bug

Comment: @Enlico, not a bug actually :)

Comment: Er, isn’t this just C-o C-e? And you may want to include an expr-map in case the popup menu is showing.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble, you put a big shame costume on me :)

Comment: Sorry! Not the intent :)

Comment: For my own memory (it took quite a while to find it), I'm linking to [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/39738/why-inoremapping-c-e-shadows-c-e-completion-functionality) I asked a few months later.