# Why inoremapping <c-e> shadows <c-e> completion functionality?

Tags: key-bindings, autocompletion, insert-mode

### Foreword

Open a new file with `vim -Nu NONE` and insert the following text (`|` is to indicate the position of the cursor, in insert mode)

```
longline
lo|
longerline
```

Now hit <kbd>Ctrl-X</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-N</kbd> and the autocompletion list will pop up, and the first entry, `longerline` will be highlighted.

If you now hit <kbd>Ctrl-Y</kbd>, the autocompletion list will disappear and the line will be reverted to what it was, like in the snipped above. What's happened is described at [`complete_CTRL-Y`](https://vimhelp.org/insert.txt.html#complete_CTRL-Y).

If you hit <kbd>Ctrl-Y</kbd> again an `n` will be inserted, and if you keep hitting it, more an more letters will appear until the second line looks like the first one. What's happening is described at [`i_CTRL-Y`](https://vimhelp.org/insert.txt.html#i_CTRL-Y).

The point is that two different functions correspond to <kbd>Ctrl-Y</kbd> depending on whether we are in insert mode with a completion list showing up or in insert mode without a completion list showing up.

### The question

However, if now I enter `:inoremap <C-Y> <C-O><C-Y>` (which I requested [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/38584/6498)), then <kbd>Ctrl-Y</kbd> will have this mapped effect not only when I'm in insert mode without the pum showing up, but also *with* the pum showing up.

Is this a bug?

Comment: You ar mapping `<C-y>` while talking about `<C-e>`.

Comment: I case somebody (or myself) can't make reason of my question because the repro steps seem wrong, I think something must have changed in Vim recently, I believe, as the statement _"If you now hit Ctrl-Y, [...] the line will be reverted to what it was"_ in my question is now false, as Ctrl-Y will actually confirm the current selection from the popup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this a bug?

This is not a Vim bug, if that is what you are asking, more like an oversight on your part and the part of the person who made the original suggestion.

This observation of yours is correct:

> The point is that two different functions correspond to <kbd>Ctrl-E</kbd> depending on whether we are in insert mode with a completion list showing up or in insert mode without a completion list showing up.

The problem is just that you didn't proceed to the logical conclusion, which that you need to take the presence of the popup menu in account if you want your mapping to override the native functionality in one case while preserving it in the other.

This is typically done with an `:help <expr>` mapping:

```
inoremap <expr> <C-e> pumvisible() ? "\<C-e>" : "\<C-O>\<C-e>"
```

where you use a ternary expression to do a plain `<C-e>` if the popup menu is visible or a fancy `<C-o><C-e>` if it is not.